# Dropping columns in Azure Data Factory based on values in columns

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm working with a dataset where I need to drop some columns which contain only `NULL` values. The issue is that the column names are not consistent or similar, and can change with time. I was wondering if there is a way in ADF to drop a column if all instances are `NULL` without having drifted columns?

I have tried unpivoting, removing rows, then re-pivoting, however after I pivot the data back to its original format, I get the following message:

> "This drifted column is not in the source schema and therefore can only be referenced with pattern matching expressions"

The drifted columns don't seem to join on subsequent join functions. I have also tried setting derived columns with regex column patters to make all the drifted columns explicit, however, the `byName()` function doesn't seem to work with the `$$` syntax; namely:

```
toString(byName($$))
```

Any ideas of how to solve this within Azure Data Factory - Data Flows would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I have used combination of both data factory pipeline activities and dataflow to achieve the requirement.
- First, I have taken dataflow to output a file. I have added a new column with all values as `1` so that I can use aggregate on all other rows using this new column to group.

[image]

- I have used collect() to create an array for each of the column where group by is on above created column.

[image]

- Now create another derived column to replace the array by converting array to string and calculating length. If length is 2 it indicates that column contains all nulls.

[image]

- Write this dataflow output to a file. The data preview of the sink will be as follows:

[image]

- Create a dataflow activity to run the above dataflow and pass the following dynamic content in execute pipeline activity to filter out and write data of only required columns.

```
@activity('Data flow1').output.runstatus.profile.sink1.total
```

[image]

- In pipeline2, I have used activities to get columns that are not entirely nulls, create a dynamic schema and then use this schema as mapping and write to a file only the required columns.
- First, I have read the file written at the end of dataflow without header (even though the file has header). The dataset looks as shown below:

[image]

- You can directly use the following pipeline JSON to build the pipeline:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline2",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Lookup1",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "cols",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Lookup1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@range(0,pipeline().parameters.count_of_rows)",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Append variable1",
                            "type": "AppendVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "props",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "Prop_@{item()}",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach2",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@variables('props')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Append variable2",
                            "type": "AppendVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "req_cols",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@if(and(not(equals(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0][item()],'tp')),not(equals(activity('Lookup1').output.value[1][item()],'2'))),activity('Lookup1').output.value[0][item()],'')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Filter1",
                "type": "Filter",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach2",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@variables('req_cols')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "condition": {
                        "value": "@not(equals(item(),''))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach3",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Filter1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Filter1').output.Value",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Append variable3",
                            "type": "AppendVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "mapping",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@json(concat('{\"source\":{\"name\":\"',item(),'\"},\"sink\":{\"name\":\"',item(),'\"}}'))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable1",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach3",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "dynamic_schema",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@concat('{\"type\":\"TabularTranslator\",\"mappings\":',string(variables('mapping')),'}}')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Copy data1",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Set variable1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                            "quoteAllText": true,
                            "fileExtension": ".txt"
                        }
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "translator": {
                        "value": "@json(variables('dynamic_schema'))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "csv1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "req_file",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "count_of_rows": {
                "type": "int"
            }
        },
        "variables": {
            "props": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "req_cols": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "test": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "mapping": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "dynamic_schema": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

[image]

**NOTE:** In the copy data activity, the source is the original file.

Answer (score 0):

If the source column names will change, then you have to use column patterns. When you match columns based on patterns, you can project those into columns using the Select transformation. Use the rule-based mapping option in the Select transformation with true() as the matching expression and $$ as the Name As property like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! I tried using the Select transformation, but this doesn't seem to solve the drifted columns. The column names, column order, and number of columns can change, the only thing in common with the column that should be dropped is that all the values in a column are the same character. Ideally I would need to select based on the conditional that all _values_ in each column are `NULL`.